# External definition and inline definition

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, inline-functions

`gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

---

I'm experimenting with inline and external definitions and here are 2 source files linked together:

`foo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void){
    printf("Test external definition\n");
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline void foo(void){
    printf("Test\n");
}

int main(void){
    foo();
}
```

Compiling an linking 2 files together `Test` is printed in console.

`N2346::6.7.4/p6` provides that:

> It is unspecified whether a call to the function uses the inline
> definition or the external definition.

and

> If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation
> unit include the inline function specifier without extern , then the
> definition in that translation unit is an inline definition. An inline
> definition does not provide an external definition for the function,
> and does not forbid an external definition in another translation
> unit.

So in the example there are *inline definition* and *external definition*. And it's unspecified which one is called.

I ran tests and in my case the inline definition was called. **Is there a way to force `gcc` to call external definition? Maybe there is some flag?**

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why can't you rename one of the two functions to make their names unique and thereby work around the issue? If you're banging your head against unspecified (or worse undefined) behavior then the solution usually is to change the code so the behavior becomes well-defined.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There's no problem in renaming. I'm actually exploring how the Standard and a particular implementation works (Sorry if the question was asked in some confusing way). Added language-lawyer tag.

Comment: @4386427 Yes, the external definition is provided in another translation unit. But we have an inline definition with external linkage.

Comment: @4386427 The question is if it's possible to control which definition is called (`inline` or `external`) in `gcc`?

Comment: Since the "main" translation unit doesn't know anything about the external definition, the compiler simply can't generate a call to such an (unknown) external function. All it can do is use the function it knows about, which is the `inline` function defined in the same TU.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is an example in the Standard at `N2346::6.7.4/p10`. Here is it's fragment: `inline double cels(double t){ return (5.0 * (t - 32.0)) / 9.0; }` is the only declaration of the function `cels` in the translation unit. And here is what goes next: _Because cels has external linkage and is referenced, an external definition has to appear in another
translation unit (see 6.9); the inline definition and the external definition are distinct and either can be used for the call._

Comment: @4386427 Looking at the example I cited in the commment above the wording suggests that there is still a choice to make. Or how should this wording be interpreted?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Didn't really get the point you're making. As the Standard says _an external definition has to appear in another translation unit_ which is exactly what I did in my example.

Comment: @4386427 Well, `fahr` does not have an inline definition since it was declared with `extern`. `6.7.4/7` _If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline function specifier without extern , then the definition in that translation unit is an inline definition._

Comment: @4386427 In my example I provided an inline definition (exactly as `cels` in the Standard). The Standard is pretty clear that _An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit._ and _It is unspecified whether a call to the function
uses the inline definition or the external definition_.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _Since the "main" translation unit doesn't know anything about the external definition,_ I disagree about that. It knows since `foo` is declared with external linkage inside the `main` TU.

Comment: @4386427 _External definition_ and _external linkage_ are different concepts. Declaration of an identifier for a function with external linkage is defined at `6.2.2` and it does not depend on being an `inline`. External definition in turns depends on being `inline` explicitly, `6.9` _An external definition is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an object_

Answer (score 1):

Citing from 6.7.4/10:

> A file scope declaration with `extern` creates an external definition.

For the external definition to be available to choose from (however the compiler chooses) there must actually be an `extern` function declaration.

From the example:

```
inline double fahr(double t) { ... }

...

extern double fahr(double); // creates an external definition
```

Comment: `6.7.4/7`: _If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline function specifier without extern, then the definition in that translation unit is an inline definition._ Therefore `fahr` does not have a inline definition so there is no any choice to make for `fahr`.